# Checking the status of a network adapter

Tags: c#, network-programming

I need to check if a network interface is currently connected to a network, disconnected, or if it's been disabled.
Consider the gross code below:

```
NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface;
            while(true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(nics[4].OperationalStatus);
            }
```

What this never ending loop does is check the operational status of a network interface card. When the loop starts, the status is Up, but when I disconnect from the network or manually disable that NIC, operational status will remain Up.

How can I check if a specific NIC is connected, disconnected, or disabled? I would like to accomplish this without having to ping an external source.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200798/how-can-i-see-if-a-network-connection-changes-state